# MySQL Query with 2 or more Filters

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask if it is possible to have 2 filters in one mysql query?

Can you show some examples?

Comment: why not? Just use `AND/OR` in `WHERE` clause!

Comment: yes. use `AND` or `OR` eg. `WHERE a=1 AND b=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE Cond1 = "value1" AND Cond2 = "value2"
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE Cond1 = "value1" OR Cond2 = "value2"
```

[**MySql Where Clause**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)